# OSX command find -type f -exec file {} \: not working

Tags: bash, macos, find

I'm trying to script changing files that do not have DOS line endings to change them to have DOS line endings, but I'm hungup on how to locate the files that don't contain DOS line endings.

I have the following command that works on linux

```
$ find -type f -exec file {} \; | grep -v CRLF
```

it works and returns

```
./test/test.bat: ASCII text
```

However, on OSX I get

```
$ find -type f -exec file {} \; | grep -v CRLF
find: illegal option -- t
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
```

I've also tried

```
$ find . -type f -exec file {} \; | grep -v CRLF
cannot open `' (No such file or directory)
cannot open `' (No such file or directory)
cannot open `' (No such file or directory)
cannot open `' (No such file or directory)
... etc
```

Is there different syntax that should be used with find on OSX to accomplish this?

Comment: OSX is bsd-based, and doesn't have much GNU stuff in it. osx find is not gnu find, and has different command line options.

Comment: The only obvious non-POSIXism here is omitting the `path` and relying on it using `.` as a default.

Comment: This has more to do with the files in the current directory than with the actual command, I think. The error messages are coming from `file`, as if `{}` were being replaced by `""`.

Comment: @chepner, agreed. That particular sequence seems unlikely, but other nonprintable characters (or characters followed by backspaces &c. to *render* as empty) in filenames is plausible. Though why they'd then result in that particular error is a bit surprising -- perhaps if they're broken symlinks? I'd need to look at how OS X's `find` deals with the scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The BSD `find` used on MacOS X requires a path to be provided before the expression (your `-type f` being part of that expression); hence its usage message putting `path` outside of `[brackets]`, which indicate that something is optional.

---

Use `--` to prevent filenames from being treated as options, and explicitly pass `.` as the location to search.

```
find . -type f -exec file -- '{}' + | grep -v CRLF
```

...has been explicitly tested on MacOS 10.11.6.

---

To better track down the error, consider the following:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c '
  for result; do
    file "$result" 2>/dev/null || {
      printf "Unable to run file against %q\n" "$result"
    }
  done
' _ {} +
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `_ {} +` means at the end please?

Comment: `_` is a placeholder for `$0` such that subsequent arguments become `$1` and later. `-exec ... {} +` tells `find` to put as many matches as will fit on a single command line, whereas `-exec ... {} ... \;` runs a separate command per match (much less efficient, if your command could be written to have multiple filenames passed to a single invocation!); you'll find those listed as the two possible ways to use `-exec` in the man page to `find`.